# Encoding problem: utf8mb4 Database with Latin1 to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have MySQL database table "PRICES" that is set `SET NAMES utf8mb4;` with colum name "TYPE" `char(70) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci`

When I get the data in PHP 5.6.40 with Pear like this:

```
    $DSN = "$db_schema://$db_username:$db_password@$db_host/$db_database";
    $db = DB::connect($DSN);

    $db->setFetchMode(DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    $db->Query("SET NAMES utf8mb4");

    $prices = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM prices");
```

Now I expect the column "TYPE" in the variable `$prices["type"]` to be some Cyrillic words but instead I get this `Ñåìååí ñ äâå äåöà`

I tried also:

`$db->Query("SET NAMES utf8");` which get the same result as above

`$db->Query("SET NAMES latin1");` which get this result => `������ � ��� ����`

I tried to convert the last result with some php functions like utf8_encode() too, but things just get worst...

So, please, if somebody here knows where the issue is, I'm glad to hear your answers!

**UPDATE**

Here you can view the sql dump file for more details: https://pastebin.com/0pig4B1j

Comment: I would start with `COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware generally you don't care for the COLLATE but rather for CHARACTER SET. Either way it could be a problem for the existing database.

Comment: Is the data in DB UTF8? Is it stored there correctly? If it isn't stored correctly you can't get it back. Similar to using black and white film and wanting color photo prints.

Comment: @user3783243 obviously not, otherwise SET NAMES latin1 would have worked. It's 1251. and you can get it back

Comment: @YourCommonSense The multibyte char(s) are not lost when written to ASCII column?

Comment: @user3783243 it's only the opposite: trying to write non-lower ASCII into multibyte column will result in ???? in database. But single-byte column will hold anything acting effectively as binary.

Comment: @user3783243 either way, currently the data is not multibyte, it's single-byte cp1251 (or so I bet, as there is little choice for Cyrillic).

Comment: here is the sql dump file:
[link](https://pastebin.com/0pig4B1j)

Comment: @markamber if you don't need to keep the existing data, simply configure the entire application to use utf-8.  If you do, then you will need to convert your data the way described [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/)

Comment: The type is Семеен с две деца, right?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thank you for the help mate and all of you guys!
The problem in my case was that I don't have to UPDATE/CHANGE database. I only read from it and get the data. So the solution I found is to get the data in PHP with `SET NAMES latin1` because this is the charset of the table. After that I looped every row and used `$v["type"] = iconv("CP1251", "UTF-8", $v["type"]);` to convert Cyrillic to UTF-8.